# How to join two files in linux?

Tags: command-line, join

I want to join two files on a Linux machine. I want to join the lines only included in the first file.

First file is unzipped file (no header, only one column).

```
1_4
3_4
4_63
6_2
```

Second file is gz file (with header, 16 columns).

```
CHR POS rsid SNPID Allele1 Allele2 AC_Allele2 AF_Allele2 imputationInfo N BETA SE Tstat p.value p.value.NA Is.SPA.converge
1  4  78  42   850   284   102   478   199    3777   485  2.5   2.4   23  35  336
8  3  74  24   0   2485   21   48   9    77   85  0.5   5.4   42  4312  335
many more lines
```

I tried as below.

```
join -11 -21 <(cat file1 | sort -k1,1) <(zcat file2.gz | sed 1,1d | awk 'NR>1{print $1"_"$2,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' | sort -k1,1) | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$5,$9+$10,$8,$11,$12,$7}' > outfile
```

The output file includes not only the lines included in the first file. Does anybody know what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one error that means you will miss the first line from file2. You have both `sed 1,1d` which will delete the first line, the header, but also `NR>1` in the `awk` which will again skip the first line. You probably wanted this instead:

```
join -11 -21 <(cat file1 | sort -k1,1) \
             <(zcat file2.gz | awk 'NR>1{print $1"_"$2,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' | sort -k1,1) |
     awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$5,$9+$10,$8,$11,$12,$7}'
```

That said, everything else should work as you describe. I tested using these example files:

```
$ cat file1
1_4
3_4
4_63
6_2
```

and

```
$ zcat file2
CHR POS rsid SNPID Allele1 Allele2 AC_Allele2 AF_Allele2 imputationInfo N BETA SE Tstat p.value p.value.NA Is.SPA.converge
1  4  78  42   850   284   102   478   199    3777   485  2.5   2.4   23  35  336
1  8  78  42   850   284   102   478   199    3777   485  2.5   2.4   23  35  336
```

And, as expected, I only got one line of output, for `1_4`:

```
$ join -11 -21 <(cat file1 | sort -k1,1) \
               <(zcat file2.gz | awk 'NR>1{print $1"_"$2,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16}' | 
                    sort -k1,1) | 
    awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$5,$9+$10,$8,$11,$12,$7}' 
1_4 1 4 850 42 677 102 3777 485 284
```

If this is not what you are seeing, please edit your question and include an example we can actually use to reproduce the error.